# tableViewCell.backgroundView acting wierd?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, background-image

I have a tableView with 8 static cells. Each cell represent a 'theme' - and I would like the background for each cell to be a specific photo.

I have used 'self.myCellName.backgroundView' before without problems. But something is different now and it doesn't set the backgroundView - only sets small coloured things in each side of the cell, see the photo: 
[image]

Can anyone help me on how to set the whole cell's background to be the photos? Is there another way? - Or am I just messing this way up somehow?

Current code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.blankCell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Blank"))
    self.pergamentCell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Pergament"))
    self.blueSkyCell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "BlueSky"))
    self.greenGrassCell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "GreenGrass"))
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: we are not going to find the problem in your project from that small snippet of code. show how you create the tableView and cells.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but why do you have instances of your cells? TableView cells are meant to be used by dequeueing.

Comment: Well, it's almost the first time I'm working with static cells, but I thought the whole point of static cells was when needed a set of different cells with input in the cell that doesn't need to change based on user interaction. So I just created the cells in my UIStoryboard and gave the labels the correct titles - then I assigned the cells to outlets in the corresponding viewController

Comment: Please check that the background color of label. It is looking as white, it might be the reason the background image is not visible correctly. It seems that the imageView is set backgroundView correctly like the 'blue sky' is stretched from end to end if you see.

Comment: Did you check whether the label's background colour is set to clear within the cells?

Comment: Jesus - I fell stupid! Thanks a lot! It was the background color of the label!! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough points to add comments to ask if there's problem with the labels background, but I'm sure that there is anything with white background in front of your image background, to check what is it, you could use this inspector:

[image]

To use it, please follow this apple's guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html

hope it helps you :)